# Is there a way to combine a bunch of coordinates in R to form a polygon? Can we also find the outline of the polygon?

Tags: r, polygon, spatial, surface, boundary

I have a bunch of (x,y) coordinates that I obtained by thresholding a 3D plot. When I plot the coordinates I get this surface:

[image: The surface I obtained]

These points are densely packed (the area in the middle is not colour fill, it's all points) and have an irregular shape. How do I obtain the boundary of this surface?

I tried saving the points as a SpatialPolygon object but that included the points in the middle. I want to only extract the boundary somehow and save that as a polygon.

Can I save these points as SpatialPoints and somehow dissolve the points in the middle?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [plotting a curve around a set of points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577918/plotting-a-curve-around-a-set-of-points) In particular, you will be interested in the second answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/13579969/8386140, which uses `alphahull::ahull()` to get the boundary of the points in a scatterplot